# Динамическое обновление PHP переменной с помощью JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Здравствуйте! Есть скрипт, который находится в `index.php` и передает `js`  переменную в этот же файл:

```
<script>
$(function(){

$('.btn').on('click', function(){
        var one = '1';
        $.get( 'index.php', { one:'one'}, function (data) {
        alert(data);
        });
    });
 });
</script>
```

Вывод результата в `index.php`:

```
if(isset($_GET['one']))
{
    echo $_GET['one'];
}
```

Но почему-то не работает( Такое ощущение что в `index.php` вообще ничего не приходит. `alert` вообще выводит шапку страницы

Comment: в консоли ошибки есть? у вас скобки не закрыты в js

Comment: php обработчик должен быть в отдельном файле без всяких скриптов и html... так что положи его куда-либо и обращайся уже туда

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev, это я когда здесь писал пропустил, а так ошибок нет

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, здесь я привел упрощенный вариант, чтобы проще было понять. На деле мне нужно после клика отправить `ajax` запрос, чтобы получить `data` и передать `data` на ту же страницу где мы кликаем, чтобы соответствующие переменные на этой странице обновились. Пока получается только получить `data`. Как мне правильно это все организовать?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, P.S. `data` я получаю из другого файла

Comment: `Есть скрипт, который находится в index.php и передает js переменную в этот же файл......... И обработчик который находится в index.php` - как это объяснить?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, Извините, я сам запутался и вас запутал. Под 'обработчиком' я имел ввиду вывод результата

Comment: если `if(isset($_GET['one']))
{
    echo $_GET['one'];
}` поместить в отдельный, например `test.php` файл без остального кода и в `ajax` делать запрос на тот отдельный файл `$.get( 'test.php'` то что выведет?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, только в адресной строке передается `http://test.php?one=one` , если в инструментах разработчика смотреть, а `if(isset(...))` не срабатывает. И запрос идет очень долго

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, немного переделал код, и каким-то чудом все заработало)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, это если у меня `$.get( 'sql.php', { ... });` и `if(isset($_GET['one'])) { echo $_GET['one']; }` в разных файлах. Но как можно сделать чтобы это в одном файле было?

Comment: @r.mcreal нет! я в самом своем первом комментарии что написал?  **php обработчик должен быть в отдельном файле без всяких скриптов и html** ...... а всё почему, потому что `echo` это отдача информации в буфер.... а html код это что? это также отдача некоего ответа в буфер, а js в файле это что? это код заключенный в html теги который отдает контент a буфер. логика понятна? в итоге у тебя всё отдается как ответ. именно поэтому (и не только) обработчики должны быть в отдельном файле.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, прошу прощения, не могли бы Вы простенький пример написать чтобы понятнее стало

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, пожалуйста

Comment: `не могли бы Вы простенький пример написать чтобы понятнее стало` -
 простенький пример чего?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разделите обработчик, используйте:

- index.php (откуда берутся данные и куда они возвращаются после обработки ajax-запроса);
- script.js (обработчик событий, отправка ajax-запросов);
- subs.php (обработчик ajax-запроса);

Скрипт:

```
js:

$(".element").on('click',function(){
    // при клике по элементу записываете значение параметра, наприммер $(this).val().trim() или $(this).html().trim();
    var param_1 = 1;

    $.ajax({ 
        // Отправляете на другой PHP-скрипт (грубо говоря, обработчик события на сервере, где производите действия)
        url: 'subs.php', 
        type: 'POST',
        dataType : "json",
        data:{
            param_1: param_1
        },
        success: function(response){
            // меняете значение контейнера на то, которое вернул AJAX-Запрос
            $('.cont').html(response); 
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Произошла ошибка");
        }
    });             
});
```

---

```
php: 

<?php
// Обрабатываете данные, присваиваете переменной, проверяете, производите манипуляции и т.п.

$param_1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'param_1', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

echo (isset($param_1)) ? json_encode($param_1) : json_encode("Вы прислали пустую переменную 'param_1'"); // отправляете обратно

?>
```